# Allow a button to give points FOR a certain amount of time in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I am only seeing articles on how to do something after a certain amount of time, but I want to know how to do something FOR a certain amount of time in Android.

```
    public void buttonClick(View v) {

        currentUser.changeScore(10);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        tv.setText("Score: " + currentUser.getScore());

    }
```

I want to the user to be able to press the button and gain points for 10 seconds after an Event has occured. After those 10 seconds, I want the user to lose 10 points if the button is pressed.

Comment: What do you mean by "gain points for 10 seconds"? Repeatedly, e.g. gain 5 points per second? Or gain 10 points once, then lose them again after 10 seconds?

Comment: For 10 seconds, every time the button is pressed, gain 10 points. For instance if I pressed it 5 times within those 10 seconds, I would have 50 points. Lose 10 points each time the button is pressed outside of the 10 seconds.

Comment: So what *starts* the 10 seconds? And should that change the score as well?

Comment: I have an Event, and each time that Event happens the 10 seconds begins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. Every time your event happens, set a variable, like this:

```
long positivePointEndTime = 0;

// In your event handler...
positivePointEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;

// Then in the button click handler
int scoreChange = System.currentTimeMillis() < positivePointEndTime ? 10 : -10;
currentUser.changeScore(scoreChange);
```

It's not like you're really wanting anything to *change* on a regular basis during that interval - the event is just setting a new point in time as the boundary of when it's "good" to click the button. No need for a timer or anything like that.

(For testability you may want to have a dependency-injected `Clock` type or something similar to provide the "current time" functionality, but the basic principle is the same.)

Comment: I forgot to ask what the meaning of the "?" was. I have never seen that before.

Comment: @mjrichards: It's the [conditional operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Now I have a new problem. When the event happens, I want a timer to wait 16 seconds after that event to trigger the button to enable points again for once again, 10 seconds. I have been trying to use Timer, but I am having some difficulty with it.

Comment: @mjrichards: What do you mean by "trigger the button"? Do you need the UI to change? It's not really clear what you're trying to do, or what you've tried, or the result. It's probably worth asking as a separate question, with code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: My event handler is triggered by a sound received by the microphone. From your proposed solution, I have the positivePointEndTime in my event handler and it works perfectly. I am trying to create another "positivePointEndTime" that will happen 16 seconds after the event handler is triggered. Then once that 16 seconds is up, I want to do the same thing in your proposed solution

Comment: @mjrichards: Sorry, that's still not clear - it's not clear whether you need more code to execute 16 seconds later, or you just need a timestamp which is set to 16 seconds after the event. Again, I think it makes sense to ask a new question about this, with code etc, rather than try to figure it out in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Timer:

```
timerIsOn = true; // timerIsOn is boolean variable, must be visible for button click handler
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timerIsOn = false;
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 10000);
```

Then button click handler will be:

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
    if (timerIsOn) {
        currentUser.changeScore(10);
    } else {
        // reduce score
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    tv.setText("Score: " + currentUser.getScore());
}
```

Comment: Would the Timer be in the event handler?

Comment: I don't understand your question quiet well. You have to 1) set flag to true 2) start timer (which will set flag to false after 10 s) 3) check flag in your click handler to do proper score changing